# Pulp: optimization

Tags: supply-chain

Given the input data:

1. `Stock[pl,p][t]` where `pl` is plant, `p` is product, `t` is time horizon.
2. `Cost[p,pl]['Cost']` where `pl` is plant, `p` is product.
3. `Price[c,p]['Price']` where `c` is cost, `p` is product.
4. `Order[o,p,t]['Quantity']` where `o` is Sales orders, `p` is product, `t` is time horizon. Here the `t` is delivery dates.

Comment: What is your question at all? It is just a list of input data, it looks like you edited it and erased something by wrong.

Comment: User removed I think

Answer (score 1):

(As you have done)
$Delv_{pl,p,t} \le Stck_{pl,p,t} $

$O_{c,p,t}^k (\delta_{k,pl}-1) \le \sum_p \tau_{c,pl}Delv_{pl,p,t} \le \sum_p O_{c,p,t}^k \delta_{k,pl} \ \ \forall pl \in Pl \ \ \forall t \in T \ \ \forall c \in C \ \forall k \in$ Orders

$ \sum_{pl} \delta_{k,pl} \le 1 \ \ \forall k \in $Orders

where $\delta_{k,pl} =1$ if plant $pl$ is selected for order# $k$, else 0 and $ \tau_{c,pl}=1$ if Pl is among those where customer $c$ sources from.

$\delta$ is a binary variable while $\tau$ is given. You can use set membership logic as well like $ C_pl = \{pl: pl \in $ Customer sources for C}

In your case you are using length of set in Constraint (3)

I don't think any of your constraints are addressing this in this way.
Constraint (2) is saying 'get product $p$ from one or all (that what sum does) plants'. Trying replacing $=$ with $\le$ as there's a chance that a product in an order will not be delivered from the plant chosen. Constraint (3) is then attempting to restrict number of plants involved in every order to 1 but there in the constraint you are coding p_ == o.

Comment: updated the code with a check constraint, still the solution is infeasible. Here is the input data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HI1oouuTyKb9ef9S4U7EnFnf5_7uJd_r/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101807459327721282405&rtpof=true&sd=true

I feel not all of these constraints may be infact required as well. What do you think?

Comment: I'd suggest use the previous code (you were perhaps on same track as my formulation) and there instead of where you used p_==o, correct it as p_==p and correct the constraint about the summing across products instead of plants.

Comment: I have reverted the code. correct the constraint about the summing across products instead of plants. - Are you referring to constraint 4? The constraint 2 sums across products to check if quantity of all products in a sales order come from same location is same as quantity requested in sales order.